# Wrong description for tag [c#-nameof]

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-excerpt

Description for the tag [c#-nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-nameof) is:

> In C#, `nameof` expressions are a **form of reflection**. They return the
>   string representation of the argument, as seen by the compiler.

But reflection means ability of a program to know/adjust its structure at **runtime**, see [Reflection (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). `nameof`, at least in C#, is evaluated **at compile time** by the compiler (another program) and hence not a reflection or its form.

I thought something like this:

> Operator to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable,
>   type, or member.

should be less confusing.

Is there a possibility to modify the tag's description?

Comment: Go to [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nameof/info) and click on [Edit Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/118438). Have fun :)

Comment: Tip: provide a reference in your edit description. Reviewers might not be experts in the subject, and inclined to reject changes that are both shorter, simpler and have a different meaning. Providing references for factual changes helps it get accepted faster.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Good hint!

Comment: I have queued an edit for the tag, so previous description, if edit will be approved, can be found in history.

Comment: I would in any case add the fact that `nameof` gets evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser It would be possible, but from the over side there are SO questions about it, so information can be found and description remains short.

Comment: True, there are questions. But I think that this is the biggest misunderstanding people have about this operator.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Maybe you are right, but I'm not sure, that it belongs to description. Feel free to adjust the description.

Comment: @DragandDrop I can't follow you.. What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

I have serious doubts about the usefulness of this tag. There are only so many questions to be asked about `nameof` before the majority of them should be closed as duplicates.

I'd rather see it deleted instead of working out a tag description.

Comment: In my opinion this tag is also not really usefull, but it doesn't disturb me comparing with **wrong** description of it.

Answer (score 0):

There's *runtime* reflection and there's *compile-time* reflection - it's not just the latter. The two uses are, in particular, in use among C++ language developers/enthusiasts. And I would definitely see a `nameof()` language construct as a reflection feature.